# insert special characters in mysql database using python angularjs

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs

How do I insert a value in MySQL that consist of single quotes. i.e

"I am joy's brother and trying to get a 'job' "

The single quote is creating a  problems.When I am trying to write some text using single quotes in text field. I am  getting an error in the console i.e,.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

How do you insert single quotes through the user interface (front end) using angularJs ,MySQL.

Comment: You need to escape such special characters with the `\\`.

Comment: That depends on how you're handling your strings right now and what database adapter you use. Show some code, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
conn.escape_string()
```

Look into what escape_string does. In a nutshell it takes your string and replaces the special characters with ex \x00.

See: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

otherwise just put a \ infront of the characters to escape them yourself! :)

Comment: hello @Tim Hinz thanks for your reply. I tried the solution and it did not work.

Comment: I got the solution  worked perfectly used.replace(" ' "," ' ' ")  Thanks a lot for the help